# Backbone: Collection inside model object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I think I have some problem with understanding Backbone .
Why inside collection -> models [0] -> children I see collection with all elements of collection. 
What is purpose of having collection inside models.We use much more memory to create objects.

Answer (score 1):

The models simply hold a reference back to their containing collection.  It's not a deep copy of the same collection.  From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor):

> The `model.collection` property is otherwise added automatically when you first add a model to a collection.

Comment: But this might be problem when I gonna have for example collection of 100 elements. So 100x100 using much memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is there so the model can generate a URL. i.e. if the collection has a URI /collections/ then the default model's url function will return /collections/1 for the model assuming the model has an id.